# Error in using Decoder swift Nested JSON

Tags: json, swift

I want to parsing a JSON get from server but I have error i don't know why?!! 
this is my struct:

```
struct MyResponse:Decodable {
    let cats: [Cats]
}

struct Cats: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let menu: [Cats]
    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case id
        case menu = "SubMenu"
    }
}
```

and create this extension :

```
extension MyResponse.Cats {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let valus = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try valus.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        id = try valus.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        menu = try valus.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .menu)
    } 
}
```

I don't know how to parse this json. This json is very important because this is category of store of store. and this is my json value :

```
{
"cats": [
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "کسب و کار ها",
        "menu": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "فروشگاهی",
                "menu": [
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "ورزشی"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "name": "نوشت افزار"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "خدماتی",
                "menu": ""
            }
        ]
    },
```

maybe in future menu now nil have sub menu 
how to handle if menu is nil or have some data ??

Edit: and this line in init :

```
menu = try valus.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .menu)
```

have this error :

> Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[MyResponse.Cats]'

Comment: Does your JSON really include a submenu entry as `"menu": ""`? If so, I’d fix whatever generates that JSON rather than programming around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON example includes an entry that says `"menu": ""`, whereas your structure assumes it is either another `Menu` instance, `null`, or completely absent.

As vadian pointed out, if your submenus sometimes come back as `""`, you can write a custom `init(from:)` method that manually parsed the JSON, as he illustrated. But better would be to fix whatever generated that JSON, so that the `"menu":""` was not present at all, or if it was, it would be `"menu":null` (note, no quotes). It's better to fix the original problem in the JSON, rather than writing cumbersome JSON parsing `init(from:)` to handle the problem.

Assuming you fix the JSON, there is, as others have noted, another problem. Your `Menu` structure defines a property called `submenu`, but your JSON doesn't use that key. It uses `menu`. So, you either can:

1. Change the property name:

   ```
   struct Menu: Codable {
       let name: String
       let id: Int
       let menu: [Menu]?
   }
   ```

   or
2. Use `CodingKeys` enumeration:

   ```
   struct Menu: Codable {
       let name: String
       let id: Int
       let submenu: [Menu]?

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case name, id
           case submenu = "menu"
       }
   }
   ```

   or
3. Change the JSON to use `submenu` key.

---

Assuming you fix the JSON, this demonstrates that you can parse it quite easily. This uses approach 2, shown above:

```
let data = """
    {
        "cats": [
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "کسب و کار ها",
                "menu": [
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "فروشگاهی",
                        "menu": [
                            {
                                "id": 17,
                                "name": "ورزشی"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 18,
                                "name": "نوشت افزار"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "name": "خدماتی"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Respons: Codable {
    let cats: [Menu]
}

struct Menu: Codable {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let submenu: [Menu]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, id
        case submenu = "menu"
    }
}

do {
    let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Respons.self, from: data)
    print(object)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for key `menu` can be

- An array of `Cat`
- An empty string
- The key is missing

So you need to write an custom initializer which handles the cases. The easiest way is to decode an array of `Cat`. If it fails assign an empty array.
Further you need an umbrella struct for the root object.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
     let cats : [Cat] // it's recommended to name structs in singular form.
}

struct Cat : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let menu : [Cat]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, id, menu }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        do {
            menu = try values.decode([Cat].self, forKey: .menu)
        } catch {
            menu = [Cat]()
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively declare menu optional

```
let menu : [Cat]?
```

and assign `nil` if the value is not `[Cat]`

```
... } catch { menu = nil }
```

`decodeIfPresent` does not work because the value can be two different types.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `Cats` structure conform to `Codable` protocol and add an optional array `[Cats]?`.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

struct MyResponse: Codable {

    let cats: [Cats]
}

struct Cats: Codable {

    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let menu: [Cats]?
}

// create json mock by encoding

let cats3 = Cats(id: 3, name: "3", menu: nil)
let cats2 = Cats(id: 2, name: "2", menu: nil)
let cats1 = Cats(id: 1, name: "1", menu: [cats2, cats3])
let myResponse = MyResponse(cats: [cats1])
let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myResponse)

print(String(bytes: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)) // Optional("{\"cats\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"1\",\"menu\":[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"2\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"3\"}]}]}")

// create category data by decoding json (your actual question)

do {
    let myResponseAgain = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse.self, from: json)
    for cats in myResponseAgain.cats {
        print(cats.id) // 1
        print(cats.name) // 1
        print(cats.menu) // Optional([__lldb_expr_30.Cats(id: 2, name: "2", menu: nil), __lldb_expr_30.Cats(id: 3, name: "3", menu: nil)])
        print(cats.menu![0].id) // 2
        print(cats.menu![0].name) // 2
        print(cats.menu![0].menu) // nil
        print(cats.menu![1].id) // 3
        print(cats.menu![1].name) // 3
        print(cats.menu![1].menu) // nil

    }
} catch {
    print("something went wrong")
}
```

Comment: thank for answer me i use this code but have error: "error : typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>"