# parsing with swiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

Hi I've created this class to parse my json with SwiftyJSON
but I'm getting error 
my class is :

```
class getMenu {
var id:Int?
var name:String?
var menu:[getMenu]?
func pasrs(json:JSON){
    self.id = json["id"].intValue
    self.name = json["name"].stringValue
    self.menu = json["menu"].arrayValue
}}
```

and the response Json get from API :

```
{
"cats": [
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "کسب و کار ها",
        "menu": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "فروشگاهی",
                "menu": [
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "ورزشی"
                    },
```

**The error**

> Cannot assign value of type '[JSON]' to type '[getMenu]?'

What should I do!?

Comment: [Very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703017/error-in-using-decoder-swift-nested-json/48796511#48796511). Why don't you use the more convenient `Codable` way? From perspective of efficiency SwiftyJSON became obsolete as JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

menu property is type of Array, then you should set its value in this way:

```
self.menu = json["menu"].arrayObject as? [getMenu]
```